# Extra width space being added?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Hello Stackoverflowers.

I am completely confused on the output of this site? It is completely finished but my container, or whatever it is is extending way beyond 1000px...

I cannot work out why, any help please do, I just wan't to be pointed in the correct direction; I have also added a jQuery tag incase someone who is good at jQuery my notice that it could be a problem with my Galleria plugin, but I doubt it? :/

http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattoos/

The link above is the page itself, and for those that may be interested in my HTML it is here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xml:lang="en-US">
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Steve A Tattoo Artist</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=EB+Garamond' rel='stylesheet' type="text/css">
<!--[if lt ie 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/styles/ie7.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt ie 7]><link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/styles/ie6.css" type="text/css" /><![endif]-->
<link rel="pingback" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/xmlrpc.php" />

<!--DEMO CSS LINKS-->
<link href="http:/www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/themes/blue-and-grey/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!--FANCY BOX REFS-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<!--GALLERIA-->
<script src="/galleria/galleria-1.2.6.min.js"></script>
<script src="/galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js"></script>
<script>Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');</script>

<!--FANCY BOX JAVA-->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
/* This is basic - uses default settings */
$("a#single_image").fancybox();

/* Using custom settings */
$("a#inline").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
});

/* Apply fancybox to multiple items */  
$("a.group").fancybox({
    'transitionIn'  :   'elastic',
    'transitionOut' :   'elastic',
    'speedIn'       :   600, 
    'speedOut'      :   200, 
    'overlayShow'   :   false
});

<!--STEVE A DIV-->
$("#firstpagename, #firstpagename2").click(function () {
$("div#white").toggle();
$("div#v2black, div#v3black").hide();
});

$(".toggle").click(function(){
      $(".toggle").hide();
      $(this).toggle();
});

});
<!--MAIN TOP NAV SCROLLING-->

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 591) {
        $(".altstevenav:hidden").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".altstevenav:visible").hide();
    }
});

$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() >= 591) {
        $(".topwhiteborder:hidden").show();
    }
    else {
        $(".topwhiteborder:visible").hide();
    }
});
</script>
<!--END OF DEMO CSS LINKS-->

<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Steve A Tattoo Artist &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Steve A Tattoo Artist &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/comments/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Steve A Tattoo Artist &raquo; tattoos Comments Feed" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattoos/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='jquery.fancybox-css'  href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.fancybox.css?ver=1.2.6' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='admin-bar-css'  href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.css?ver=20111209' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.7.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.fancybox.js?ver=1.2.6'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/plugins/fancy-box/jquery.easing.js?ver=1.3'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/comment-reply.js?ver=20090102'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<link rel='prev' title='sketchbook' href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/sketchbook/' />

<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.3.1" />
<link rel='canonical' href='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattoos/' />
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        var select = $('a[href$=".bmp"],a[href$=".gif"],a[href$=".jpg"],a[href$=".jpeg"],a[href$=".png"],a[href$=".BMP"],a[href$=".GIF"],a[href$=".JPG"],a[href$=".JPEG"],a[href$=".PNG"]');
        select.attr('rel', 'fancybox');
        select.fancybox();
    });
</script>
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
<style type="text/css" media="print">#wpadminbar { display:none; }</style>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html { margin-top: 28px !important; }
    * html body { margin-top: 28px !important; }
</style>
</head>

   <body class="other">

<div class="header"></div>

<div class="content">
    <div class="main">              <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=170028539732171";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!--POP UP MENU-->
 <div class="alt2stevenav">
    <div class="stevenav">
        <ul class="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com">Steve A</a>

            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattoos/">Tattoos</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/sketchbook/">Sketchbook</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!--MAIN CLOSING DIV-->
</div>
<!--CONTENT CLOSING DIV-->
<!--ALL DIVS ARE CLOSE HERE-->
<div id="v2black">
<div class="galpos">
<br />
<div class="gallery">
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image1.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image1.jpg" alt="Image 1"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image2.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image2.jpg" alt="Image 2"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image3.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image3.jpg" alt="Image 3"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image4.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image4.jpg" alt="Image 4"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image5.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image5.jpg" alt="Image 5"></a>

<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image6.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image6.jpg" alt="Image 6"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image7.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/image7.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/stevewithbackpiece.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/stevewithbackpiece.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/snakeface.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/snakeface.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/skullladies.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/skullladies.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/ship.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/ship.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/littleboots.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/littleboots.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/legfootpiece.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/legfootpiece.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/jesus.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/jesus.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/headpiece.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/headpiece.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/halfsleeve.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/halfsleeve.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/ellaeviechloe.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/ellaeviechloe.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/egyption.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/egyption.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/detail.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/detail.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/chinesegirl.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/chinesegirl.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/calligraphy.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/calligraphy.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/backdragon.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/backdragon.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>

<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/angel.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/angel.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
<a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/296061_1719365923046_1805246243_1108346_8286262_n.jpg"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/tattooslider/296061_1719365923046_1805246243_1108346_8286262_n.jpg" alt="Image 7"></a>
</div>
<div class="posfb"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/" data-send="true" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true" data-font="arial"></div></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="sttopwhiteborder"></div>
</div>
<!--END OF CHANGING DIVS-->
<div style="display:none">
<div id="data" style="width:800px; height:400px;">
<br />
<div class="steveacontact">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
  <tr>
    <td width="325"><h2 style="color:#ffc600; text-align:center; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;">How to reach Steve</h2></td>

    <td rowspan="2"><iframe width="440" height="300" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="http://maps.google.co.uk/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q=179+Old+Christchurch+Road+Bournemouth+Dorset+BH1+1JU&amp;sll=50.722405,-1.869851&amp;sspn=0.011547,0.031757&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=179+Old+Christchurch+Rd,+Bournemouth,+Dorset+County+BH1+1JU,+United+Kingdom&amp;ll=50.722405,-1.869851&amp;spn=0.005773,0.015879&amp;t=h&amp;z=14&amp;output=embed"></iframe><br />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="325"><p style="font-size:16px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, Sans-Serif; text-align:center;">Indelible Tattoo Studio<br />
     <span style="color:#ffc600;"> 179 Old Christchurch Road<br />
      Bournemouth<br />

      Dorset<br />
      BH1 1JU<br />
      </span></p>
      <p style="text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;">info@indeliable-tattoo.co.uk</p>
      <p style="text-align:center; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#ffc600;">Tel: 01202 315316</p>
      <p style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:0px;"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1805246243"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/facebook.jpg" border="0" alt="Steve A Tattoo Facebook" /></a></p>
      </td>

  </tr>
</table>
<br />
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div style="display:none">
<div id="copy" style="width:370px; padding:10px;">
<div style="border-style: double none; padding:10px 0px;">
<h2 style="color:#ffc600; font-family:Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; text-align:center;">The legal stuff</h2>
<h3 style="font-size:16px; color:#555555; text-align:center; margin-bottom:-5px; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;">© 2012 steveatattooartist.com</h3>
<p style="text-align:center; color:#555555; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:10px 30px; font-size:14px; line-height:22px;">You should assume that everything you see or read on this site is copyrighted unless otherwise noted. Nothing contained on the site should be construed as granting, by implication, or otherwise, any license or right to use anything displayed on the site without written permission. While we have used reasonable efforts to include accurate and up to date information in this site, we make no warranties or representations as to its accuracy. We assume no liability or responsibility for any errors or omissions in the content of the site.</p>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-includes/js/admin-bar.js?ver=20111130'></script>
        <div id="wpadminbar" class="nojq nojs" role="navigation">
            <div class="quicklinks">
                <ul id="wp-admin-bar-root-default" class="ab-top-menu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/about.php" title="About WordPress"><span class="ab-icon"></span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-about" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/about.php">About WordPress</a>       </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-wp-logo-external" class="ab-sub-secondary ab-submenu">

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-wporg" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://wordpress.org">WordPress.org</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-documentation" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://codex.wordpress.org">Documentation</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-support-forums" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://wordpress.org/support/">Support Forums</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-feedback" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://wordpress.org/support/forum/requests-and-feedback">Feedback</a>       </li></ul></div>        </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-site-name" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/">Steve A Tattoo Artist</a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-site-name-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-dashboard" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/">Dashboard</a>      </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-appearance" class=" ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-themes" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/themes.php">Themes</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-widgets" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/widgets.php">Widgets</a>       </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-menus" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/nav-menus.php">Menus</a>     </li></ul></div>        </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-updates" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/update-core.php" title="2 Plugin Updates"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">2</span></a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-comments" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/edit-comments.php" title="0 comments awaiting moderation"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span id="ab-awaiting-mod" class="ab-label awaiting-mod pending-count count-0">0</span></a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-content" class="menupop"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post-new.php" title="Add New"><span class="ab-icon"></span><span class="ab-label">New</span></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-new-content-default" class="ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-post" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post-new.php">Post</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-media" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/media-new.php">Media</a>     </li>

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-link" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/link-add.php">Link</a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-page" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page">Page</a>     </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-new-user" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/user-new.php">User</a>        </li></ul></div>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=99&#038;action=edit">Edit Page</a>      </li></ul><ul id="wp-admin-bar-top-secondary" class="ab-top-secondary ab-top-menu">

        <li id="wp-admin-bar-search" class=" admin-bar-search"><div class="ab-item ab-empty-item" tabindex="-1"><form action="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/" method="get" id="adminbarsearch"><input class="adminbar-input" name="s" id="adminbar-search" tabindex="10" type="text" value="" maxlength="150" /><input type="submit" class="adminbar-button" value="Search"/></form></div>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-my-account" class="menupop with-avatar"><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" aria-haspopup="true" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/profile.php" title="My Account">Howdy, clairewild<img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/63344d548f5d2204635a85802d53cf97?s=16&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D16&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-16 photo' height='16' width='16' /></a><div class="ab-sub-wrapper"><ul id="wp-admin-bar-user-actions" class=" ab-submenu">
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-user-info" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="-1" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/profile.php"><img alt='' src='http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/63344d548f5d2204635a85802d53cf97?s=64&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2F0.gravatar.com%2Favatar%2Fad516503a11cd5ca435acc9bb6523536%3Fs%3D64&amp;r=G' class='avatar avatar-64 photo' height='64' width='64' /><span class='display-name'>clairewild</span></a>        </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-edit-profile" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-admin/profile.php">Edit My Profile</a>      </li>
        <li id="wp-admin-bar-logout" class=""><a class="ab-item" tabindex="10" href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&#038;_wpnonce=fed8cab26c">Log Out</a>     </li></ul></div>        </li></ul>          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="menu">
<div class="middle">
<ul style="margin-top:6px; margin-left:70px;">
<li><a href="http://www.steveatattooartist.com">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="inline" href="#data">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.steve-a.co.uk/">The Illustrated Man I</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.indelible-tattoo.co.uk/">Indeliable Tattoo Studio</a></li>
<li><a href="http://www.bournemouthtattooconvention.com/artists.php">Bournemouth Tattoo Convention</a></li>

</ul>
<ul style="margin-top:5px;">
<li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=1805246243"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/fb.jpg" height="17" width="16" alt="facebook icon for steveatattooartist" /></a></li>
<li><a id="inline" href="#copy"><img src="http://www.steveatattooartist.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/copyright.jpg" height="17" width="17" alt="" /></a></li>
</ul>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
Galleria.loadTheme('galleria/themes/classic/galleria.classic.min.js');
$(".gallery").galleria({
width: 1000,
height: 650,
});
});
</script>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am completely STUMPED.

Comment: can you name which container...and also do you wan the width of the site to be 1000px?

Comment: Why on earth do you have so much CSS inside your HTML? Also about your post - TL;DR. Simply add a CSS rule .gallery { max-width: 1000px; }. Because right now there is no CSS that controls the width of your gallery div.

Comment: According to Chrome Developer Tools the div element with class name "gallery" is less then 1000px. Exactly what element is too wide? The black background? The Facebook bar?

Comment: I found it in the end! It was indeed the facebook bar! - Thank you to those that helped.

And I'm cleaning it up now, got messy as times went on! Bad Practice :P